# Prove $\alpha i=i\alpha$ iff $c=d=0$. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb H$ and $\alpha=a+bi+cj+dk, a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, quaternions

Prove $\alpha i=i\alpha$ iff $c=d=0$. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb H$ and $\alpha=a+bi+cj+dk, a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Q$.

**My Attempt:**

**$(\rightarrow):$** $$\alpha i=ai-b-ck+dk \Rightarrow -b+ai+dj-ck$$

$$i\alpha =ai-b+ck-dk \Rightarrow -b+ai-dj+ck$$

Thus, $\alpha i =i \alpha$ because $d=-d$ and $c=-c$ implies $c=d=0$.

**$(\leftarrow):$** If $c=d=0$ then,

$$(a+bi+0j+0k)i=i(a+bi+0j+0k)$$
$$(a+bi)i=i(a+bi)$$
$$ai-b=ai-b$$
Thus, $\alpha i = i \alpha$.

I'm not positive if I'm allowed to begin the second part with the equivalence:$(a+bi+0j+0k)i=i(a+bi+0j+0k)$. I know when you're trying to prove two things equal you can't start the proof with stating the equality as true. Does it work in this instance because we are stating $c=d=0$ first, then plugging them in?

Comment: ................Why is that not allowed? Would it help if you reverse the order of the 3 equations?

Comment: I would rephrase: "Thus, $\alpha i=i\alpha$ **only if** $d=-d$ and $c=-c$ implying that $c=d=0$." In this part your **assumption** is that $\alpha i=i\alpha$, so we are interested in what we can deduce from that. Your sentence structure gave (at least) to me the impression that $\alpha i=i\alpha$ was a consequence of $d=-d$ and $c=-c$, warping the logic. (+1) for showing your work.

Answer (score 0):

Call $[\alpha,\beta]$ the commutator of two quaternions; then it is not hard to see that this is a bilinear product. Moreover $[1,i]=0$ and $[i,i]=0$. Knowing this, calculate $[\alpha,i]$, and make use of the fact that $j$ and $k$ are linearly independent.